# WebStorm not opening in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command, webstorm, ubuntu-15.04

I recently installed jetbrain's WebStorm 10 at Ubuntu 15.04. It was working fine earlier but after a OS restart today, it's not opening. Clicking WebStorm icon at launcher doesn't open it. Is there any command that i may try at terminal to open Webstorm?
PS: I'm new to Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Just type `wstorm` in a terminal, assuming you didn't change the default config values it should launch it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it.

Case 1. Since you can see the icon, run the below command with sudo permissions in terminal.

```
   sudo wstorm
```

Case 2. If you don't see the icon while searching.

Go to the directory where WebStorm is installed. (Usually, it is /usr/local/bin, or, /usr/local, or /usr/bin), and run the command above command.